# Installing OpenVPN on Windows7

Tags: openvpn, drivers, windows-7

It seems I cannot install the current version of OpenVPN (2.1.2) because the TAP driver is not signed and therefore windows 7 x64 refuses to install it.
It shows up in the device manager, but with a yellow exclamation mark.
It's a fresh system, and OpenVPN was never installed before.

When I start the OpenVPN client it seems to connect fine, but then it stops with

```
CreateFile failed on TAP device: ...
All TAP-Win32 adapters on this system are currently in use.
```

How can I  install the unsigned drivers, or are there signed drivers available somewhere ?

Comment: You can try [this solution](http://www.fiberworks.com/DNN/Support/OpenVPN/tabid/171/language/en-US/Default.aspx). Worked for me, but it's kind of ugly.

Comment: Check if your **TAP-Win32 Adapter** is enabled from control panel - network center...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install, the application has to be run in Vista Compatibility mode.

Download OpenVPN 2.1 and then :

```
1) After downloading, right-click on the file and select 'properties' then 'compatibility mode'
2) Select 'Windows Vista (Service Pack 1)'
3) For privilege level, select 'Run this program as administrator'
4) Click 'Apply' and then 'OK' to exit
5) Double-click on the installation file install. Agree to any questions that pop up. Click next where prompted.
Note: The installation of the TAP adapter can sometimes take up to a minute. Do not exit the installer while the TAP adapter is being processed.
```

Once the program is installed you need to mark OpenVPN-GUI in compatibility mode with Vista(SP1) and then mark checkbox "Run As an Administrator".

Comment: his unfortunately doesn't work. I removed the device along with its drivers from the device manager and uninstalled OpenVPN. During the re-install when asked to install the unsigned driver I clicked yes, but the end result was the exact same.

Comment: Just tried with an older version (2.1 RC19) and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

It may work to install software that disable Windows enforcing of signed drivers.
I think that for me worked software [EASYBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). Go to its Advanced config and tick to Allow use of unsigned drivers. Reboot. I am not sure if reinstallation of the OpenPVN is necessary.